# Get up to topmost parent

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Explain my problem with sample.

I have three tables `ledger, balance, group`.

Columns are

```
  ledger ---> no, name, groupno
  balance --> ledgerno, balance
  group --> groupno, groupname, undergroupno
```

I want to show the ledger with top most parent which has balance > 0.

**ledger**

```
no   name  groupno
1     A      5
2     B      4
```

**balance**

```
ledgerno balance
 1          100
 2          200
```

**group**

```
groupno groupname undergroupno 
 1         AA        0
 2         BB        0
 3         CC        1
 4         DD        1
 5         EE        1
 6         FF        1
 7         GG        2
 8         HH        2
 9         II        2
 10        JJ        2
```

So I want the result like this:

```
name     balance

 AA     
  CC
  DD
   B      100
   EE
    A     100
    FF
```

I tried the below `with query` but it does not show the right results

```
WITH rel AS (
    SELECT groupname, amount
    FROM (
        WITH RECURSIVE rel_tree AS (
            SELECT groupno, groupname, undergroupno
            FROM "group"
            WHERE undergroupno = 0
          UNION ALL
            SELECT groupno, groupname, undergroupno
            FROM balance b
            INNER JOIN ledger l ON l.no = b.ledgerno
            INNER JOIN "group" g ON g.groupno = l.groupno AS tt
            INNER JOIN rel_tree r ON r.groupno = tt.undergroupno
        )
        SELECT *, 0 AS amount
        FROM rel_tree
        GROUP BY groupno, groupname, undergroupno
    )
SELECT *
FROM rel
UNION ALL
SELECT groupname, amount
FROM (
    SELECT name AS groupname, balance AS amount, groupname AS ord
    FROM balance b
    INNER JOIN ledger l ON l.no = b.ledgerno
    INNER JOIN "group" g ON g.groupno = l.groupno) AS ta
INNER JOIN rel ON rel.groupname = ta.ord
```

Using **postgresql 9.3**

Comment: Consider formatting your queries when asking this type of question.

Comment: http://sqlformat.org

Comment: Compute the groups tree, keeping a reference of the root node or the path. (You'll find an example query that does this in the manual.) Then join it with ledgers and balances.

Comment: The Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, NEVER EVER use a SQL reserved word as a name for a table or a column. NEVER. EVER. Below I use **grp** instead of **group**.

Second, use column names that are immediately clear. Below I use **parent** instead of **undergroupno**.

Third, this is a really nice problem that I happily spent some time on. I am using recursive data structures myself and getting the query right is always something of a puzzle.

Fourth, what you state that you want is rather impossible. You have output on multiple lines from one table (grp), which is interspersed with data from other tables. I have a solution that comes quite close to what you specified. Here it is:

```
WITH tree AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE rel_tree(parent, groupno, refs, path) AS (
        SELECT groupno, groupno, 0, lpad(groupno::text, 4, '0') FROM grp WHERE parent > 0
    UNION
        SELECT g.parent, t.groupno, t.refs+1, lpad(g.parent::text, 4, '0') || '.' || t.path FROM grp g
        JOIN rel_tree t ON t.parent = g.groupno)
    SELECT * FROM rel_tree WHERE parent > 0 
    UNION
    SELECT groupno, groupno, 0 AS refs, lpad(groupno::text, 4, '0') FROM grp WHERE parent = 0)
SELECT repeat(' ', t.refs) || grp.groupname AS name, l.name AS ledger, b.balance
FROM grp
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (groupno) groupno, parent, max(refs) AS refs, path
    FROM tree
    GROUP BY parent, groupno, path
    ORDER BY groupno, path) t USING (groupno)
LEFT JOIN ledger l USING (groupno)
LEFT JOIN balance b ON b.ledgerno = l.no
ORDER BY t.path
```

This gives the output:

```
name, ledger, balance
AA
 CC
 DD, B, 200
 EE, A, 100
 FF
BB
 GG
 HH
 II
 JJ
```

**A few words on the recursive-with query:**

This query yields a self-inclusive complete hierarchy. What this means is that it lists for every node of the hierarchy all of its parents, including itself. If you run the **tree** CTE as a separate query, you will find that it returns more rows than the 10 in the **grp** table.This is because it lists all **grp** records with their **groupno** as **groupno** but also as **parent** and additionally all parent nodes higher up in the hierarchy. Such a self-inclusive complete hierarchy is very handy when analyzing other properties of recursive data structures, such as containment and parentage.

Note that the hierarchy is built from the bottom up, starting with every node having itself as a parent, a refs value of 0 (i.e. 0 referrals between *parent* and *self* and a path which is just the **groupno** as a text value (padded with 0's). The recursion works its way up the hierarchy with increasing ref values and longer paths. The sub-select in the main query trims the complete list down to a single record for each **grp** record, which can be ordered by **path**. (Note that the use of **refs** can be omitted and replaced by **length(path)**, but **refs** does have uses in other contexts of using a similar query.)

This query works to greater depths of the hierarchy as well. If you add:

```
11        KK        8
12        LL        8
13        MM        11
```

to table **grp**, the query will output:

```
name, ledger, balance
AA
 CC
 DD, B, 200
 EE, A, 100
 FF
BB
 GG
 HH
  KK
   MM
  LL
 II
 JJ
```

Note that the **path** works with **groupno** values up to 9999. For larger **groupno** values increase the leading 0's in the recursive CTE, or consider using the **ltree** extension for more flexibility.